# Checking whether set is closed or open

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\mathbb N × \mathbb Q$ with the subspace topology of the usual topology of $\mathbb R^2$. Let $P=\{(n,\frac {1}{n}): n\in \mathbb N\}$. Then check whether $P$ is closed or open or both.

I think P is closed but not open. Since P does not have a limit point outside P it is closed. If P is open then we must have some open set U in $\mathbb R^2$ such that $P=U\cap X$. Which is not possible as $U\cap X $ will contain infinitely many points other than $(n,\frac{1}{n})$. Am I right?

Comment: It is not an interval it is a point of the set $\mathhbb N × \mathbb Q$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for closedness is correct. To show that it is  not open consider $(1,1)$. Let us show that this is not an interior point. Suppose some open neighborhood of this point is contained in $P$. Consider the points $(1,1+\frac 1 N)$. These points do not belong to $P$ but they will lie in the neighborhood for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: The interior will be an empty set right?

Comment: Yes, you can work with any $(n,\frac 1 n)$ instead of $(1,1)$ and show that no point is an interior point. @Mathfun

Answer (score 0):

Your are correct. If $\langle n,q\rangle\in X\setminus P$, then $q\ne\frac1n$. Let $U=\Bbb Q\setminus\left\{\frac1n\right\}$; then $\{n\}\times U$ is an open nbhd of $\langle n,q\rangle$ disjoint from $P$, so $P$ is closed in $X$. Not only is $P$ not open: it has empty interior. Let $p=\left\langle n,\frac1n\right\rangle\in P$; $p$ has a local base of open nbhds of the form

$$\{n\}\times\left(\left(p-\frac1n,p+\frac1n\right)\cap\Bbb Q\right)$$

for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, and clearly none of these sets is contained in $P$.